# How to get message field in a rich push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, richpush

I'm developing an application with a notification inbox using Urban Airship.

A rich push notification contains title and message. It's sent as a JSONObject, i.e.:

> {"aliases": ["user@mail.com"], "push": {"aps": {"alert": "ei!"}}, "title": "New notification", "message": "This is a rich push test!"}

When I get my inbox and I try to open a RichPushMessage, I only can get title and send date. There isn't a method to get the JSONObject ([UrbanAirship API](http://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/richpush/RichPushMessage.html))

**How I could retrieve the message field?** I've seen about "*RichPushMessageView*" component, but I don't like to show the notification as a webpage. I only need the message field and show it in a textview.

Comment: Did you get solution. Can you help me i am also stuck here.